# AWS S3 file only for special user

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to upload images from users and upload to S3. The problem is, that the images should only be display from the user itself and not invoke by other people who know the url.

I think it is possible to return the image from a url in my application an check the session data if the user is valid. Maybe http://img.domain.com/31hh21ej12he/

But is there a way in S3 to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate pre-signed URLs, they will be much harder to "guess" or share and expire after a while. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html